# Sum quantity based on 3 unique cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a large amount of data and I need to consolidate unique rows based on 3 columns and then sum the value in a fourth. the problem is excel can only look at one column at a time to consolidate duplicates. the source data looks similar to this.

```
g|a|b|10|c|l
g|a|b|10|c|l
g|x|y|10|v|l
g|x|y|10|v|l
```

and I need it to look like this

```
g|a|b|20|c|l
g|x|y|20|v|l
```

I need it to maintain the same layout and remove the duplicates as well
sorry for the miss clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely looks like a task for SUMIFS function.

Assuming your data starts in column A the following would give you the sums:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A1,B:B,B1,C:C,C1)
```

Put the sum in a new column, copy+paste as values, remove column with single values (D in this case) and remove duplicates using all columns. You will be left with exactly what you wanted.

[image: Here's an example of using this function]

Comment: So I guess that's not a super good example of my data it really looks more like what I've edited it to.

Comment: @TylerBurr It will work with abc/zxc as well. It sums up all rows where columns A through C have the exact same values. If you still think it does not work, please create a counter example.